# javascript data scraping wikipedia table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page

```
<script>
var convertToInt;
var allData = [];

$.ajax({
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Europe",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var root, body, table;
        root = $("<div></div>")
        root.html(data.responseText)
        var rows = root.find("table tr:not(:has(th))");  
        $.each(rows, function(index, value) {
            var datatest = $(this.find("td"));
            console.log(datatest);
        });
    },  
    error: function() {
        return console.log("error");
    }
});
```

But the console returns the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'find'"`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
datatest = $(this).find("td");
```

You missed the `)`