# How to pull data from Wikipedia page

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, wikipedia

What is the best way to pull the data from the table of this wikipedia page using just JavaScript?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_Spanish

I've tried using the following code to get the JSON, but it hasn't worked. Then once I get the JSON, how would I grab the data from the table?

```js
fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_Spanish')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(response){
   console.log(response)
  })
```

Comment: Check out your console error - not possible client-side unless you route through another server, or are already on the domain you want to scrape

Comment: You could use the official Wikipedia API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript data scraping wikipedia table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318170/javascript-data-scraping-wikipedia-table)

Answer (score 2):

This code will get you tables as html nodes:

```js
var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&origin=*&page=Most%20common%20words%20in%20Spanish';

fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(response){
    html_code = response["parse"]["text"]["*"];
    parser = new DOMParser();
    html = parser.parseFromString(html_code, "text/html");
    var tables = html.querySelectorAll(".wikitable");
    console.log(tables);
  })
```

I am using [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to get html of Wikipedia page as json response. You can find documentation for this type of API request [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse).